# Should i always use 'else:' even it is not necessary?

Tags: python

Am i must to use here `else:` or i have opportunity to remove it and just type `return True`

```
def some_function(x):
  if another_function(x) == -1:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

**EDIT:** I know how to make this code compact with just one return. The main question is about `else:`.

Comment: There may be two schools of thought here. I slightly prefer just the plain `return True` after the `if`.

Comment: `return another_function(x) != -1`

Comment: Simplify: `if condition: return True else: return False` --> `return condition` and `if condition: return False else: return True` --> `return not condition`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers and molbdnilo: That was my thought as well, but I see it as an example where the essential question is about the necessity of `else:` instead of the concrete code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should i always use 'else:' even it is not necessary?

I myself believe that they are not necessary. Returning at the beginning of the function in case of edge cases is something that allows you to skip sometimes lots of indentations caused by `else`s:

```
def some_function(x):
    if edge_case_1:
        return []
    if edge_case_2:
        return None

    #a
    #lot
    #of
    #code
    #here

    return result
```

looks better than

```
def some_function(x):
    if edge_case_1:
        return []
    elif edge_case_2:
        return None
    else:
        #a
        #lot
        #of
        #code
        #here

        return result
```

right?

But it's not only about the looks:

- Elses like that make you easily confuse the indentation levels.
- The line width becomes smaller because the indentation takes those few character, you might need to format your code more to fit PEP8.
- Sometimes you write the main part of the code first, only to discover the edge cases later. Version control systems such as git would mark all indented lines as changed (depending on the configuration), while the only thing you did was add those ifs at the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

you can remove else and do like this:

```
def some_function(x):
  if another_function(x) == -1:
    return False

  return True
```

Answer (score 2):

Logically you can write

```
def some_function(x):
    return another_function(x) != -1
```

Comment: It was just example function. The main question is about `else:`

Answer (score 0):

For the general case: since the `return` exits the function at this point and return control to the caller, the prefered idiom is :

```
def foo(x):
    if <some_expression>:
        return <something>
    # we'll only ever get here if `<some_expression>`'s value is false
    return <something_else>
```

As to why it's the prefered idiom (in python at least): the general consensus is that it makes the code more readable by 1/ flattening it (less indentation levels) and 2/ getting rid of all corner cases right from the start so the nominal case code is not polluted by such considerations. As a general rule, the simpler the code (and "flat" code is simpler than nested one, at least for the human brain) the easiest it is to understand.

Now for your own case where you are returning the boolean value of an expression, you don't even need a `if` statement at all - you can just directly return the result of evaluating the expression:

```
def foo(x):
    return some_test(x) != some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

else is not mandatory syntactically but there are few cases where you will get error

declare default value:-

```
var1 = some_value
if condition:
    var1 = "something"
    return var1
```